# FreeType support for right-to-left languages

Tags: right-to-left, hebrew, freetype

Does FreeType support the use of right-to-left languages, like Hebrew? I can get it to display correctly if I just reverse the string first, but this isn't as efficient. So what I am asking is there a way to configure FreeType to automatically right a Hebrew string right to left?

Comment: http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-5.html#section-4

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is a text layout library, e.g Pango see http://www.pango.org

FreeType focuses on the extraction of the glyph data from a font file; it is up to the user to implement the language specific stuff such as the layout of the text.